# Symfony 4 User, UserRoles and Roles ORM association for Login

Tags: authentication, orm, doctrine, symfony4

I want to create dynamic and multi user role login architecture in `symfony` 4.

My database tables:

**user**

(id,user_name,email,password,is_verified,is_blocked,created_at,updated_at)

**user_roles**

(id,user_id,role_id,created_at,updated_at)

**roles**

(id,name,created_at,updated_at)

How exact should I make *ORM* mapping? What I wanted is to have returned associated roles names from roles tables when calling to `getRoles()` in User class.

User.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;


/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="email", columns={"email"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_name", columns={"user_name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 */
class User implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_name", type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    private $userName;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_verified", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isVerified;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_blocked", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isBlocked;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $createdAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $updatedAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUserName(): string
    {
        return $this->userName;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $userName
     */
    public function setUserName(string $userName): void
    {
        $this->userName = $userName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail(): string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail(string $email): void
    {
        $this->email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword(string $password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isVerified(): bool
    {
        return $this->isVerified;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $isVerified
     */
    public function setIsVerified(bool $isVerified): void
    {
        $this->isVerified = $isVerified;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isBlocked(): bool
    {
        return $this->isBlocked;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $isBlocked
     */
    public function setIsBlocked(bool $isBlocked): void
    {
        $this->isBlocked = $isBlocked;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $createdAt): void
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt): void
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }

    public function getSalt()
    {
        // TODO: Implement getSalt() method.
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->password = null;
    }

    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize([
            $this->id,
            $this->userName,
            $this->email
        ]);
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        return list(
            $this->id,
            $this->userName,
            $this->email
            ) = unserialize($serialized, ['allow_classes' => false]);
    }

    public function getRoles()
    {
        // **FIXME**: return names from userRoles->Roles
    }
}
```

Role.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Role
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="roles", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="name", columns={"name"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\RoleRepository")
 */
class Role
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $createdAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $updatedAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $createdAt): void
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt): void
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }
}
```

UserRoles.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * UserRoles
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user_roles", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_roles", columns={"user_id", "role_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRolesRepository")
 */
class UserRoles
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $userId;
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="role_id", type="smallint", nullable=false, options={"unsigned"=true})
     */
    private $roleId;
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $createdAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $updatedAt = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getUserId(): int
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $userId
     */
    public function setUserId(int $userId): void
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getRoleId(): int
    {
        return $this->roleId;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $roleId
     */
    public function setRoleId(int $roleId): void
    {
        $this->roleId = $roleId;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     */
    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTime $createdAt): void
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): \DateTime
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(\DateTime $updatedAt): void
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;
    }
}
```

I've followed http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html , just I need more flexibility.

Comment: Hello, you can try to define a **ManyToMany** relationship $symfonyRoles in **User.php**. 
Now in getRoles call $symfonyRoles getter and hydrate an array with role's name.

Comment: Alexandre, could You explain how exact I should do that, what do You mean "hydrate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of All,your class UserRoles is useless because **ManyToMany** Relationship will do the job.
Better than many explainations, i provide you [doctrine's many to many example](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional).

Second step, If you are here your User Entity get an attribute like **userRoles**.
This attribute contain **Role Entity** associated to this **User**.

According to [Symfony security documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/entity_provider.html) **getRoles** method should return an array of role **BUT** our roles are **Entity**.
So to fix this you have to parse **userRoles** and populate an array with role's name.

Quick example:

```
//getRoles should look like this
public function getRoles()
{
    return array('ROLE_USER');
}

//So using $userRoles example
public function getRoles()
{
    $roles = [];
    /**
     * BE CAREFUL Doing this doctrine will do a Select for each Role
     * I advice you to configure this relationship with fetch=EAGER
     * so that doctrine will automatically Join user roles each time you find a  
     * User.
     **/
    foreach($user->getUserRoles() as $userRole) {
        $roles[] = $role->getName();
    }
    return $roles;
}
```

This is a quick implementation to show you how you can do it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct but in cases where your m:n entity / table needs additional properties like in the OP's question, you _do_ want to create the m:n entity;  `UserRole` in this case. This is in the [documentation you posted](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional). The anchor link isn't working for some reason so click "ManyToMany, Unidirectional" in the menu then scroll down a bit to see a note about this. In these cases you have 3 entities and create a `1:n >< m:n >< 1:n` relation between them.